# hex to binary (2 hex digits at a time) - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to take a hex number, for example 4e40b844800742db4f9b and convert it to decimal 2 digits at a time. For example from above take 4e convert it to decimal, the take 40, and so on

I am currently using this function to take a list of decimal numbers and convert them to hex which produces the above hex

```
def decimal_to_hex(ilist):      
    return ''.join('{:02x}'.format(i) for i in ilist)
```

Is there something a nice similar short way I can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [13]: s = '4e40b844800742db4f9b'

In [14]: [int(s[n:n+2], 16) for n in xrange(0, len(s), 2)]
Out[14]: [78, 64, 184, 68, 128, 7, 66, 219, 79, 155]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy regex you can abuse findall for making the groups

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '4e40b844800742db4f9b'
>>> [int(n, 16) for n in re.findall('..', s)]
[78, 64, 184, 68, 128, 7, 66, 219, 79, 155]
```

Will be more expensive, but I think it reads nicer.